# Minimum SDK version support for Activity

Tags: android

The application have some activities, some runs on higher version only. But since the activity support `mimeType` of `intent-filter`, so I've no control over its launch.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Like the activity having this `intent-filter` can be launched by lowered version than it must not. Eg : The activity must run in version 11 and above but android will still show it inside chooser dialog of image in lower versions. Is there a way to avoid this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for only XML configuration I can suggest you the way, how it's done in Android API Demos.

They declare `Activity` in the AndroidManifest as disabled or enabled depending on API version like this `android:enabled="@bool/atLeastHoneycomb"`, where `@bool/atLeastHoneycomb` is just a flag that is set to true in `values-v11` and to false in the default `values` folder (you can check Android API Demos, as I said previously, for more details).

Answer (score 2):

You would have to have a 'controller' activity with the `intent-filter`.

When this activity starts, it would check the current SDK level and then forward on the Intent to either the lower or higher SDK activity, then `finish()` itself.

In your situation this can give you further flexibility later, say you want to direct tablets to a 3rd activity.

---

Another argument could be that your Activity should test the SDK level and then just swap `Fragments` out dependent on this. i.e. your Activity is SDK agnostic but it is a controller for the correct Fragments to show.

References:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#version-codes

http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/abstracting.html

http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/using-component.html

As you see from the references, you should go read the training docs

Comment: That is the inbuilt support. What are you looking for a magic wand?

Comment: not a wand :) but it would be nice if there was some xml tag for it.